# Jumbotron can't get centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently started using Bootstrap. I'm having a problem with centering Jumbotron. I can't post image as example now because I need 10 reputation. My code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 jumbotron center">
            <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My css:

```
.jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
    padding: 14px 24px;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.center{
    text-align: center;
}
```

I'm sorry if solution is very easy but I'm beginner web developer.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your problem? It looks centered to me here: http://jsfiddle.net/g8LUy/

Comment: [Pic example](http://www.part.lt/img/16f77a32f2513c0074a5986b8b1a8e35132.png) I think I should change container's width. Could it be solution?

Answer (score 1):

You've set the size of your jumbotron to 8 columns on 'medium' and above (`col-md-8`) with no offsetting. This means as the screen gets bigger than what Bootstrap classes as 'Medium' it will change from 100% with to 8/12s width.

If you want this width then add an offset class of 2 (`col-md-offset-2`) or you can get rid of your `col-md-8` to force it to always be 100% regardless of device width as in this example - http://jsfiddle.net/g8LUy/1/

Full width jumbtron

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron center">
    ...your jumbtron html
   </div>
</div>
```

'8/12ths' width jumbotron

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 center">
    ...your jumbtron html
   </div>
</div>
```

You can read more on the Bootstrap grid system and the various offsetting classes on their website on their 'CSS' page under 'Grid system' - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: My 8/12ths width example may be wrong, but the jsFiddle should do what you want either way, just make sure you make your browser big (and perhaps extend the work area in the fiddle) to see it adapt.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I wasn't taking my own advice and didn't make my browser wide enough to see it happening!